# Unwanted black background around my iframe video

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, iframe, opera

[This is how the video looks with the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UepRV.png)

I have an introduction video of my website which is in an iframe. It works fine on firefox but gets a black background for the entire div in opera and chrome browser.

This is my code snippet.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 respvideo ">
    <iframe width="512" height="288" src="videos/Welcome.m4v"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>    
</div>
```

The background doesn't seem to appear when I view the video on smaller devices, but appears on devices like a tab or higher screen sized.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to iframe tag

```
allowtransparency="true"
```

and set background color to transparent